# Cisco Archiving of Logs - Rebooting device resets file count but doesn't remove files

Tags: cisco, configuration, ios, archive

We are using the cisco IOS feature of configuration archiving and it has been very useful.

One thing we are finding is that we have set the maximum file count to 14, which is fine.

Except when we reboot the router, the counter is reset and it creates another 14 files.

This could end up filling up the flash which would not be desired.

Does anyone know how we can best deal with this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at your current IOS version.  My suspicion is that this is simply a bug which hopefully has been fixed in a later version, which you'll need to upgrade to - you'll have to check the release notes for known problems & fixed problems and see if it's been dealt with.

If you've got a support agreement, you can always log it with Cisco TAC and see what they say; I've found them to be very helpful people!

Comment: I believe the IOS version has been checked as the issue appears to be consistent across a variety of devices, but I will double check :) TAC may be the next option, if we have that option :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use rancid to get (nearly) the same functionality centrally.

Many write ups of this feature mention this eg:
http://stack.nil.com/ipcorner/RouterConfigArch/

> Configuration version number is an increasing integer reset to one on every router reload.

So I rather suspect it's simply a limitation that's never been fixed, as those with Cisco's ear already use rancid style systems (or push config generators).